# Grails 3 enumType for Set of enums

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.3

How to define a mapping for **Set** with **enumType:'identity'** ?

In Grails 3.3 enumType become mandatory for [Enums with id](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/column.html) (for 3.2 it works without any additional definitions).

With Enum fields everything works well, but I don't know, how to write a mapping for Set of enums

```
class Test {
   Set<TestEnum> enums
   static mapping {
     enums  enumType: 'identity' // not works 
   }
}

enum TestEnum {
   final int id
   TestEnum(int value){
   ...
   }
}
```

Any ideas?

I know, I can use enumType:'string'. Not a case for me

Comment: I don't think this is possible currently

Comment: @JamesKleeh any fix regarding this on current version?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can create a wrapper entity :

```
class EnumWrapper {
    TestEnum testEnum
    static mapping {
        testEnum enumType: 'identity'
    }
    static belongsTo = [test: Test]
}

class Test {
   static hasMany = [enumWrappers: EnumWrapper]
}

enum TestEnum {
    final int id
    TestEnum(int value){
    ...
    }
}
```